# Android: how to persistently store an array of floats

Tags: java, android, database, arrays, floating-point

I've used SQLite databases before for simple login/user data storage. Now I have a bit of a data problem:

Say I have an array of 500 floating point values. How should I persistently store - and be able to quickly retrieve - such a data structure? It's literally just float[500] (max I could see would be ~1000, to give an idea of scale). Cheers.

Comment: I mean, you could make a 1 column table with 500 rows, 1 for each value if you want to literally save the array. However I suggest you rethink your design. If you give more info as to what the data is, we can give you advice on how to store it

Comment: `TABLE: ID, FLOATVAL` `if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { floatArray = new float[cursor.getCount());` iterate cursor and put data from rows to array `}`

Comment: ... or Blob column and convert ByteBuffer to FloatBuffer `((ByteBuffer)ByteBuffer.wrap(cursor.getBlob(N)).rewind()).asFloatBuffer().get()`

Comment: @Cruncher I provided what I thought was the most important thing: storing arrays of floats. I'll store a few hundred of these arrays at most for now.

Comment: Oh, it's not a single array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this relationally with two tables.

Table 1: Array

Single column that has an id.

Table 2: ArrayData

Two columns, one with the id of which array it is, and another with the float.

Then

SELECT Data
FROM ArrayData
WHERE ArrayID=?

gives you your array.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Speed should be alright for retrieving up to 1000 real elements at a time right? I actually have no idea where one could find metrics for this sort of thing.

Comment: if you have 1000s of arrays with 500 elements each it may take a bit. But even tables with 500000 entries can rip through them pretty quick. What kind of speed are you expecting? This would be measured on the order of seconds

Comment: For now, say 500 arrays with 500 entries each. Doesn't need to scale just yet (doing some proof-of-concept work). Just need to be able to extract the array I want, then do some numerical analysis, hopefully all under a second. edit - and my numerical analysis won't be worse than N-squared algorithm on the array of size 500.

Comment: I think at the end of the day you just need data to test and benchmark. Try this, and the string conversion method. If you have few array then this is faster, the more arrays you have, the worse this solution gets.

That being said, this is the "relational" way, which everyone seems to be moving toward these days.

Answer (score 1):

@JDS,
If your familiar with the SQLLITE technology then keep using it.

Consider making a list /< object /> so your not hard coding 500 elements.  Then store the elements in a SQLLITE table with two columns id & data.  position in list for the id and string toString() method of the object for the data.  500 strings will come out of a SQLLITE database fast order by the list id and easily load them.